# How do i fix the arc issue

Tags: ios, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

How do i fix the following code

```
return [(NSNetwork*)CFDictionaryGetValue( _networkMap, address) retain];
```

fixed to

```
return [(NSNetwork*)CFDictionaryGetValue( _networkMap, (__bridge const void *)address)];
```

Its says expected identifier.I am unable to figure out.
Can u guys help me plz?

Comment: Just remove square brackets - you need them only if you're going to invoke a method.

Comment: As @kovpas says `return (NSNetwork*)CFDictionaryGetValue( _networkMap, (__bridge const void *)address);`

Answer (score 2):

Just change your return statement to this:

```
return (NSNetwork*)CFDictionaryGetValue( _networkMap, (__bridge const void *)address);
```

Hope this helps.. :)